# IoC in WCF hosted in Windows Service and container lifetime per call

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-container, soa, simple-injector

I have a few clients (web and desktop apps) that must connect to a few services which are WCF services hosted in a Windows Service. These services must get data from one or more databases, but it is the client who determines from which database, there can be one or more databases from the same type defined.

I have a setup in the service with datacontexts, repositories, business managers and an implementation for the services. Datacontext is injected by the SimpleInjector container (I also tried with Unity) and off course, the registrations in the container takes place before the creation of the ServiceHosts, which are created in context mode Single (also tried per call and per session).

I have written an implementation of the IDispatchMessageInspector that will intercept all SOAP messages and read the message header and set the database connnection string of the datacontext depending on the values in the message header.
But this will lead to problems because it is not "thread safe", or at least when one call is not finished yet, the next call will maybe set another connectionstring to the same datacontext, messing it all up.

So, I'm trying to get this registered as per call (async, wcf lifestyle) but because this is a Windows Service, it will not close and the container is not scoped properly.

What can I do in this scenario to make it work?

[image: Case 1: no problem, cases 2 and 3: it must not interfere with each other]

Container creation and service host start:

```
var container = new Container();
//container.Options.DefaultLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
DIContainer.SetDI(container);

serviceHosts.Add(new ServiceHost(typeof(LoginService)));
serviceHosts.Add(new ServiceHost(typeof(IdentityService)));

foreach (var serviceHost in serviceHosts)
{
    serviceHost.Open();
}
```

Registration of the DbContext:

```
container.RegisterInstance<CSI.AuthServices.DataAccess.EF.Interfaces.ISecurityContext>(new CSI.AuthServices.DataAccess.EF.SecurityContext());
```

Interceptor for reading SOAP message header and set database connection string:

```
ISecurityContext securityContext = m_Container.GetInstance<ISecurityContext>();
var sqlConn = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = @"DEV_TEST_SERVER\SQL2017",
    InitialCatalog = "COMMON",
    IntegratedSecurity = true,
    ConnectTimeout = 30
};
securityContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = sqlConn.ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 1):

> the ServiceHosts, which are created in context mode Single

This is a bad idea.  The integration page [states](https://simpleinjector.org/wcf):

> **TIP: Use InstanceContextMode.PerCall for all WCF services. This prevents any hard to detect problems caused by WCF services outliving a single request.**

There are two options when it comes to making contextual data (such as your request-influenced connection strings) available to parts of the application. You can either use *ambient state*, or you use that you *flow* the data with the objec graph.

Ambient state means that you store the data in some mutable state that is available for a certain context. Here are several options:

- Global Static state. Those fields are accessible by all threads and requests in the application. This is not very suited for your scenario.
- Thread-static state. Everywhere the field is accessed from a single thread, the same value is returned, but other threads get their own value. Since WCF requests can execute over multiple threads asynchronously, this options isn't suitable either.
- Async-scoped state. This allows a single logical asynchronous flow of operations to be scoped with the same data. The data is available everywhere within that scope. This option is most suited for your needs.

NOTE: For this answer, I assume the `ISecurityContext` to be defined as follows:

```
public interface ISecurityContext
{
    public Database Database { get; }
}
```

Using the third option, you can implement your `SecurityContext` as follows:

```
public sealed class SecurityContext : ISecurityContext
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<Database> db =
        new AsyncLocal<Database>();

    Database ISecurityContext.Database => db.Value;

    internal void SetDatabase(Database database) => db.Value = database;
}
```

Because of the use of [System.Threading.AsyncLocal](https://www.google.com/search?q=asynclocal%3Ct%3E&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab), you can reuse the same single `SecurityContext` instance throughout the application, registered as `Singleton`.

Inside your `IDispatchMessageInspector`, you can set the database by calling `SecurityContext.SetDatabase(db)`.

The other option is to flow data using the object graph. In that case, you store your mutable state as private fields inside contextual classes (such as your `SecurityContext` and register them as `Scoped`. This way you can set their values when the request start, and those values can be reused everywhere in the request, where `ISecuriryContext` is injected, while another request gets a different `SecurityContext` instance.

you can change your `SecurityContext` to the following:

```
public sealed class SecurityContext : ISecurityContext
{
    // Just get/set with a private backing field. No ambient state
    public Database Database { get; set; }
}
```

Register it as follows:

```
container.Register<SecurityContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<ISecurityContext, SecurityContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Inside your `IDispatchMessageInspector`, you can resolve `SecurityContext` and set the `Database`:

```
container.GetInstance<SecurityContext>().Database = db;
```

The rest of your application can simply depend on `ISecurityContext` and retrieve its `Database` value.